# (Dummit and Foote) Group of order 12

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I'm struggling to understand a point in a proof about groups of order 12. I would like some help with it.

Let $G$ be a group of order 12. This proof shows that either $G$ has a normal Sylow 3-subgroup or $G \simeq A_4$.

So we suppose $n_3 \not = 1$ by Sylow congruence and divisibility $n_3 = 4$. Pick some $P \in \text{Syl}_3(G)$. $[G : N_G(P)] = 4$. Let $G$ act by conjugation on its four Sylow 3-subgroups so we get a representation $\phi : G \to S_4$.

I understand this much.

The next part is that the kernel $K$ of this action $K \le N_G(P) = P$. Since $P$ is not normal in $G$ by assumption, $K = 1$.

Can anybody elaborate on the reasoning behind this last part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know $P$ has order $3$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $P$. Thus $K$ has order $1$ or order $3$ (Lagrange). If $K$ has order $3$, then $K = P = N_G(P)$, which means that $P$ is normal in $G$ (since the kernel $K$ is normal), a contradiction. Thus we must have $K=1$.